# Is it possible to do multiseat the systemd way with one graphic card / two heads?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, xorg, multiseat

I would like to setup a multi-seat configuration using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

After some researches, it seems the way to do now is by systemd through "loginctl" calls. (saw [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/multiseat/) for example).

Before diving too much into into the tutorials because i don't have required materials for now (have only one keyboard at hands), i would like to know if it is possible to achieve a "two seats" setup using only one graphic card having two outputs, HDMI and DVI. It seems two cards are required but i would like to be sure.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution / figure it out?

Comment: It seems to be possible with "Xephyr", but according to [ArchLinux Wiki on the subject](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg_multiseat#Graphics_hardware) it has some limitations. I have not tried myself. I have done my setup using a second graphic card. Could be great to have some feedbacks here if you try though!

Comment: @sgt-hartman Have you tried specifically using one of the outputs of the card as the device to attach in `loginctl attach-device`. e.g. `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1`?

Comment: @RianHunter I'm pretty sure i tried. I think loginctl filters out the output part. But this needs to be confirmed. I now use a two cards multiseat.

Comment: @RianHunter : I can confirm that attaching a card's output only actually results in attaching the entire graphics card.

Answer (score -3):

I also wanted to do the same thing, I found this:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiseatOneCard

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This guide is nearly 10 years old. It is not applicable with systemd, which is explicitly asked for in the OP.